# How do call C++ function through Delphi wrapper

Tags: c++, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

My first question here. Please give me a hint if I do something wrong.

My question: I have to call a c++ function through a Delphi wrapper (VCL). The delphi wrapper looks like:

```
function TFoxBurnerSDK.ReadFileContents(FilePath: string; Offset: int64; var Buffer; Length: integer; var ActualLength: integer): boolean;
begin
    CheckActive;
    if FSessionHandle=nil then begin
        FLastError:=BS_SDK_ERROR_BAD_REQUEST;
        Result:=false;
        Exit;
    end;
    Result:=DLLResult(FoxBurnerSDKCore.ReadFileContents(FSessionHandle,
      PFoxSDKChar(FoxSDKString(FilePath)), Offset, @buffer, Length, @ActualLength));
end
```

How to call this function from Delphi code. Mean what var/parameter I will need to send to the function? It seems that buffer and ActualLength are pointers in C++

```
int32 BS_CALL ReadFileContents( HSESSION hSession, const TCHAR* lpszFilePath, int64 nOffset, void* pBuffer, int32 nBufferSize, int32* pRead );
```

And that is the problem for me, how to handle the pointers in Delphi. I thought that this is the right call in Delphi:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Bytes: TBytes;
iRead : integer;
begin
SetLength(Bytes, 2352*27);
iRead:=0;

Burner.ReadFileContents('\autorun.inf', 0, Bytes, 2352*27, iRead);

end;
```

But this will cause a memory expection. If I call the function from a C++ sample it works well. Just here in Delphi an expection happen. So I think I made something wrong.

I hope I gave all needed information to get an answer. If not please let me know what I miss. Thank you.

Added information: Definition:

```
ReadFileContents : function (Session: HSESSION; FilePath: PFoxSDKChar; Offset: int64; Buffer: pointer; BufferSize: integer; Read: pinteger): integer; stdcall; 

function ReadFileContents(FilePath: string; Offset: int64; var Buffer; Length: integer; var ActualLength: integer): boolean;
```

Comment: You have to show us the definition of `FoxBurnerSDKCore.ReadFileContents`

Comment: Hi AmigoJack, I have added the tow defintions into the question.

Comment: Nowhere near enough information here. Hence downvote and close vote. Do provide full description of how to call the function, and do format your code so that it is easy to read.

Comment: run C header through H2Pas tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be defined this way:

```
ReadFileContents: function
( Session: HSESSION  // HSESSION
; FilePath: PChar  // TCHAR*
; Offset: Int64  // int64
; Buffer: Pointer  // void*
; BufferSize: Integer  // int32
; Read: PInteger  // int32*
): Integer;  // int32
cdecl;  // C++, don't know why you use stdcall
```

And the call should be

```
var
  iResult, iLength, iRead: Integer;
  sFilePath: String;
  iOffset: Int64;
  aBuf: Array of Byte;
begin
  iLength:= 5;
  SetLength( aBuf, iLength );
  iResult:= ReadFileContents( FSessionHandle, PChar(sFilePath), iOffset, @aBuf[0], iLength, @iRead );
```

Comment: Define "a". Also edited my answer to a full call example, so you don't fiddle with types which we don't know.

Comment: I got a version of the DLL where everything is commented in this function. So it just return a 0. The Function will cause a crash. So is it possible that the declare of the C++ function is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If `FoxBurnerSDKCore` defines C++ function properly, then take care about `buffer` argument. For dynamic array `Bytes` you have to use `Bytes[0]` as argument of external Delphi function

(to avoid c++ function call with 'pointer to pointer' argument value, because dyn. array TBytes internally is already pointer to array data)

Comment: I have added the definitions in the question. I also tried Bytes[0] same result.

Comment: What Delphi version are you using? If Unicode one, check `AnsiString` for `FilePath`

Comment: I use Rad Studio 10.1

Comment: In 10.1 `string` argument is Unicode. Try to change to `AnsiString` (there is no enough information to claim this clearly)

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry, this is the problem of people who switch from C++ to Delphi. After hours of debugging I have found out that the Function and its declaration was not initialized. 
I have now added:

```
ReadFileContents:=GetProcAddress(h,'ReadFileContents'); ok:=ok and (@ReadFileContents<>nil);
```

to the function list in the wrapper and now everything works perfect. Thanks to all who have given me an answer. All this answers were perfect for a beiginner and to learn something. Again, many thanks.

Comment: Note that this problem might be solved in five minutes, if you showed us MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question you asked. We could not have guessed that. Learn to create a MCVE when you ask such questions.